# Is NASA's Performance Vehicle Calculator website open for public use?

Tags: launch, nasa, calculation

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25855/12102) links to "NASA's Performance Vehicle Calculator" with the link

- https://elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov/Pages/Query.aspx

I've also found the same link in

- https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=41867.0

But when I try it, all I get is

> This site can’t be reached
>
> elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov took too long to respond.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq50B.png)

So while it does not reject me, I can not access it.

**Question:** Does this site have any restrictions based on location or otherwise? Is it in fact unavailable in general? Is it intended to be open for public use?

**edit:** I've done a quick search for `ksc.nasa.gov` and found several more KSC sites and all of them are unavailable to me, giving the same connection timeout. However, just `nasa.gov` works fine.

- https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/
- https://kscsma.ksc.nasa.gov/
- https://trmm.ksc.nasa.gov/
- https://procurement.ksc.nasa.gov/
- https://environmental.ksc.nasa.gov/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can access it without problems. There's no requirement to register and log in, that means it's a public website.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I'll keep an eye on it to see if the response improves.

Comment: I've updated the question, it seems there's a general problem between my location and anything `ksc.nasa.gov`

Comment: I had something similar with www.nasa.gov a while ago. Persisted for a few weeks, then went away. Likely a configuration error somewhere in a routing table.

Comment: @uhoh can you try using a VPN that emerges in the US to see if it's a locale restriction?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't have a VPN. That's a good idea though, if this doesn't change in a few days I'll go look for someone with one. In the mean time I'll try other internet connections/facilities.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did a quick test of some `dtic.mil` links in other questions and answers here, including one of my [own](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14456/12102), and I can't reach those either. I think living in the shadow of a large technology vacuum cleaner across the straight puts me in an unofficial "[cone of silence](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31789/what-do-the-radiation-patterns-of-ads-b-transmissions-on-large-airliners-tend-to/31797#comment80125_31789)".

Comment: @OrganicMarble update: I have had occasional success with both ksc.nasa.gov and dtic.mil in various WiFi locations around town but it's spotty. Just "one of those things" it seems.